# Query execution php script in the same page

Tags: php, mysql

I have this form html code in update.php. For updating, it's required to link to another page save_seeker.php with mysql update script for it to be executed. Is there any way to execute the script in same page on submitting form so that after query execution it remains on same page?

```
  <form action= "save_seeker.php" method = "post">
  Update details !<br><br>
  First Name
  <input type = "text" name = "fname" value = "<?php echo $disp['fname'];?>"><br><br> 
  Last Name 
  <input type = "text" name = "lname" value = "<?php echo $disp['lname'];?>"><br><br>
  Contact number
  <input type = "text" name = "contact" value = "<?php echo $disp['contact'];?>"><br><br>
  Email-id
  <input type = "email" name = "email" value = "<?php echo $disp['email'];?>"><br><br>
  Address
  <input type = "text" name = "address" value = "<?php echo $disp['address'];?>"><br><br> 
  Experience
  <input type = "number" name = "experience" value = "<?php echo $disp['experience'];?> "><br><br> 
  Qualification
  <input type = "text" name = "qualification" value = "<?php echo $disp['qualification'];?>"><br><br>
  <input type = "Submit" value = "Update">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the processing in the same file by adding this into the form action.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <!-- Input fields in here-->
    <input type="submit" name="form_submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now check for the submit action by checking if it is set in the post variable

```
<?php 
    if ( isset( $_POST['form_submit'] ) ) {
        // Do processing here.
    }
?>
```

Comment: And where is the required script to be included because I have other php scripts in the same page.

Comment: Please avoid using PHP_SELF. http://phpsecurity.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/the-danger-of-php_self/
http://www.cyberscorpion.com/2012-03/why-php_self-should-be-avoided-when-creating-website-links/

Comment: Instead of giving a name attribute to the submit element, you could just check if the $_POST[] array is empty: 

if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST){//do something} 

So you completely avoid the name attribute.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `include('page-with-update.php')` , call the update function and use the  $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].

I hope helped!!

Comment: Please avoid using PHP_SELF: http://www.cyberscorpion.com/2012-03/why-php_self-should-be-avoided-when-creating-website-links/